# List of single word English nouns?

Tags: database, search

i'm trying to find a list of popular English nouns, any list ranging from about 6000 - 20000 words would be fine. I have a list at the moment consisting of almost 150,000 nouns but many of these words are not really nouns such as 'I', 'You', 'Main' etc. It also contains entries which consist of multiple words. I could write a short script to try and filter this list but i thought there might be a better option available. I have tried a few places on the web for stuff like English language learning but most of them only contain things like 'top 1500 nouns'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time back I used some input from Stanford NLP (http://nlp.stanford.edu/), I think it's worth looking at. If they don't provide some static database they definitely have tools that will help you in cleaning up your list.